# How do I check if a date in the database is past due in my template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django so I apologize if this is something simple.
I'm trying to check if a date stored in the database is past due.
I have a "due_date" in my "Update" model and would like to check in my html if the date is past due in order to display a HTML output.
I've been looking online for hours but none of the answers seems to work.

models.py

```
class Update(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

index.html

```
{% if update.due_date <= today %}
    <td class="py-2 px-4 text-center">
        <span class="p-1 text-xs border rounded-md bg-red-100 border-red-400 text-red-600">Overdue</span>
    </td>
{% else %}
    <td class="py-2 px-4 text-center">
        <span class="p-1 text-xs border rounded-md bg-green-100 border-green-400 text-green-600">Current</span>
    </td>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a model property then use it in your template as follows:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Update(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def is_past_due(self) -> bool:
        today = timezone.now()

        return self.due_date <= today.date()
```

Then use it like so:

```
{% if update.is_past_due %}
 your html code here...
{% else %}
 your html code here...
{% endif%}
```

Comment: That did it thank you very much